# Dice roll - random numbers are not generating correctly C++

Tags: c++, random

The code below print same random numbers all the time, I think the rand() is not working properly. Please help on this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        int die1 = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        std::cout << "Generated random number:  " << die1 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code does exactly what it has been written to do. What were you expecting? Please provide a description of what is expected to do and what it does instead.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your requirements are, can you re-word your title? "Please help on this code" what's it *supposed* to do and what is it doing instead? Looks like you're just generating a random number, mod 6 and add 1 then print it out.

Comment: you know getting two six in a row is just as possible as getting 3 and then 4, righ?

Comment: I was trying **"Roll a dice"** program, my code was always printing 6 at first two positions. I came to know that **rand()** function was not working properly. Then I have added **srand(time(0));** under **main()** function and included **#include <time.h>** at the top. It worked

Answer (score 2):

A few issues (aside from your malformed `main` prototype which you ought to fix).

1. Unless you tell it otherwise, `rand()` is *seeded* with an initial value of 1. Use `srand` to change that. Using the system clock time is idiomatic. Then at least your output will vary.
2. Taking modulus 6 will introduce statistical bias unless the generator's periodicity is a multiple of 6, which is unlikely. You *will* notice that effect for such a small modulus. Use a division-based approach with `RAND_MAX` instead: `rand() / (RAND_MAX / 6 + 1)` is no more of an abuse of `rand()` than `rand()` itself is an abuse of uniformity!
3. `rand()` does not have particularly good statistical properties. Consider using the Mersenne Twister generator that's now part of the C++ standard library. For a casino-quality generator, you'd probably have to resort to using external hardware.

Whatever you adopt, you can always run a chi square test for uniformity against your sample, too see if it has adequate statistical properties.

Comment: Division doesn't work; it just changes which values are more frequent. You have to discard values returned by `rand()` that would introduce bias. Find the largest multiple of 6 that's less than or equal to `RAND_MAX` and throw away values that are greater than or equal to that value.

Comment: Discarding *will itself* introduce bias: the variance will go up. In my experience, `rand() / (RAND_MAX / 6 + 1)` was always good enough if `rand()` itself was good enough. But test it with a chi square for uniformity.

Comment: Variance is not bias. I'd rather have a higher variance than some number occurring more often than another. Discarding is standard technique when generating random distributions.

Comment: Test it by pretending that `RAND_MAX` is 6, and looking at what each technique does with the values [0, 6].

Comment: It can be an extremely pernicious technique in certain circumstances. But I'm being silly here - I'm talking about generators far more sophisticated than `rand()`.

Comment: If RAND_MAX is 0x7fff, then you're talking about being 0.02% more likely to roll a 1, or a one-in-32767 chance that any given roll shows bias. So if you're going to test it, your first challenge is to find a chi-squared table which goes to 4 decimal places rather than three. It's more significant when the range is larger compared with RAND_MAX.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 16% probability that you will get the same number twice in a row. `rand()` always return the same sequence for the same seed. What you are seeing is not necessarily incorrect. If you remove the `%`, what responses do you see? Are you seeing the same numbers?

Try calling `srand((unsigned) time(&t))` before your while loop and see the results. They should be different from one execution run to the next.